# Regarding finding middle element of a string

Tags: c#, substring, console-application

The below snippet takes a string as input. What I am trying is to get middle 2 elements of the string if the length is even.

```
        string input = "confir";
        string op = "";
        op = input.Substring((input.Length - 1) / 2,input.Length/2 -1);//logic
        Console.WriteLine(op);//display the output
```

Output for above snippet is `nf`.

When input is changed to `confirme`, output should be `fi` and not `fir`
How do I generalize? What is the error in the logic?

Comment: The error in your logic is a. using array based logic to determine length of string, if a string has 5 characters then length is 5 and b. calculating a value you already know i.e. 2 is the length of the string you wish to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "confir";
if(input.Length % 2 == 0)
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring((input.Length / 2)-1, 2));
```

That should give you the expected result.First check whether the string length is even then instead of `(input.Length - 1) / 2`, divide length by 2 and subtract 1,then take two characters like this: `(input.Length / 2) - 1`

Answer (score 2):

Second argument of [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a *length* of substring, not index like in Java. So if you need to get substring of two characters, pass 2:

```
string input = "confirme";
string op = input.Substring((input.Length - 1) / 2, 2);
```

BTW you should handle case when string is less than 2 characters long:

```
string op = input.Substring((input.Length - 1) / 2, Math.Min(input.Length, 2));
```

Tests:

```
  input    |   op   |
---------------------
""         |  ""    |
"c"        |  "c"   |
"co"       |  "co"  |
"con"      |  "on"  |
"conf"     |  "on"  |
"confir"   |  "nf"  |
"confirme" |  "fi"  |
```

Comment: And also string.IsNullOrEmpty to avoid null reference exception

Comment: @rism empty is OK, but good notice - null check is also required

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you are providing total length of the string as second argument to the `Substring()` method.

**Solution :** `Substring()` method takes total number of characters tobe removed starting from first argument .

From MSDN : [Substring(Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and has a specified length.

Replace This:

```
op = input.Substring((input.Length - 1) / 2,input.Length/2 -1);//logic
```

With This:

```
op = input.Substring((input.Length - 1) / 2,2);//logic
```

**Suggestion :** you need to check for Empty String and for Even number of charatcters in String.

**Complete Code:**

```
        string input = "confirme";
        string op = "";
        if (input.Length > 0 && input.Length % 2 == 0)
        {
            op = input.Substring((input.Length - 1) / 2, 2);//logic
            Console.WriteLine(op);//display the output
        }
```